# How to use Mozilla DevNet date polyfill in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wish to use the date polyfill [mentioned here at MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

How do I get this into a variable?  I tried:

```
function get_date_string(){
    if (!Date.now) {
        Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
    }
}

var ds = get_date_string();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}

var ds = Date.now();
```